SwiftUI List elements not registering onTapGesture after ios 18 upgrade?
I have a list that searches through a nutrition api and displays the search result in a list. Up until upgrading to ios 18, everything worked flawlessly.
Now, when the list is created, sometimes the onTapGesture is recognizes and loads the fooddetail page, with other items in the list not registering taps at all?
Why would this change suddenly? I can't figure out how to get every item in the list to be tappable now.
List(searchResults, id: \.fid) { food in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(food.name)
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    .padding(.bottom, 4)
                                Text("\(food.brand) - \(extractCalories(from: food.calories) ?? "nil")")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 8)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 8.0)
                        .padding(.top, 0)
                        .background(
                            Color(red: 40 / 255, green: 40 / 255, blue: 40 / 255)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                        )
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        print(searchResults)
                    }
                    .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Ensures the entire area is tappable
                    /*.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                            print("TAPPED FOOD ID: \(food.fid)")
                            tappedFoodID = food.fid
                            tappedFoodName = food.name
                            showFoodItemDetail = true
                        })*/
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            print("TAPPED FOOD ID: \(food.fid)")
                            tappedFoodID = food.fid
                            tappedFoodName = food.name
                            showFoodItemDetail = true
                        }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                    .padding(.horizontal, -16) // Remove horizontal padding for the whole list
                    .padding(.vertical, 0)    // Remove vertical padding for the whole list
                }



Show a minimal reproducible code that we can compile, run and produce your problem. It looks like you have a TabView and also a NavigationStack, show how these are setup and how the List is used.

I may be experiencing the same problem, I've found that if I tap and hold for a couple seconds it will register the taps. So everything that was a tap on ios17 suddenly requires a very long tap on ios18. If you see the same thing it may help us narrow this down.

I stumbled across a solution to my own problem that maybe isn't helpful enough to put as a full on answer: I found that wrapping a parent view in a NavigationStack {} made everything just start working well again. For my app, I started with it high up in the stack, just a few levels below the initial App WindowGroup. Likely somewhere there is a NavigationLink in my code that wasn't inside a NavigationStack so this at least is a hack that can now help me find the actual bug and address it correctly.

I have the same issue with VStack inside TabView. Removing TabView solves the issue. Have no idea why though

@pwb2103 Same. It works when tapping and holding for 1 or 2 seconds. I resolved it for onTapGesture using .simultaneousGesture. But Its also happening with the button's own action. I am still looking for a solution to that.

@Jam Perhaps this is unhelpful and definitely a bit time consuming, but have you tried either creating a dummy app that is just the list, or moving the list to the very top of the view hierarchy to confirm the problem is still there? I would make a testview of that list code and put it in the body of my initial App Struct. If the bug persists then you know I'm not helpful. If it goes away, you know you can blame it on something in the hierarchy.

I encountered the same problem. I modified the code to the following and it worked fine.
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .highPriorityGesture(
                TapGesture().onEnded {
                    print("TAPPED")
                }
            )


on iOS 18+, parentView's tapGesture may block childViews' tapGestures (.onTapGesture, or Button's action) -> solution: replace parentView's .onTapGesture with .simultaneousGesture.
See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/simultaneousgesture(_:including:)

It also seems to be happening with the button's action. Do you know why?

This will work if parent view has tapgesture, its overriding child view tap getsures. even buttons

I'm having the same issue but with buttons too. It's so annoying. Some elements are clickable and some not. If I change onTapGesture with highPriorityGesture as you suggested -> it works but then subviews of the view are not clickable at all. So that's not a solution I guess.
In my case, buttons have the same problem. Some of them are clickable and some not (in the list). Long press works, button action is triggered always like that, but single press is still the issue.
You can check my question too.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

I also faced same issue when I run in iOS 18 with latest Xcode 16

Tap gesture does not work properly with Webview & List.

Instead of using .onTapGesture use this .highPriorityGesture
.highPriorityGesture(
    TapGesture().onEnded { _ in
        // your code here to handle tap gesture......
    }
)

It will work in iOS 18 as well as in below versions.
iOS 17 and below it will work only.
.onTapGesture { 
// your code here to handle tap gesture......
}


I'm facing the same problem
In iOS 16 and iOS 17 I had a .onTapGesture on the parents view, and in the child view one list with items.
That items have a few swipe actions on it.
Now with iOS 18 suddenly stops working.
I already test the solutions provided and anything worked for me
Sometimes, when you swipe a few times on a items the swipe action start to work but this is not the correct way to use it.
Someone with problems in the swipe actions too?
In my case the problem was caused by compiling with Xcode 16.0. Going back to Xcode 15.4 and compiling comes back to normally again.
You can select Xcode 15.4 in Sequoia like this:
Xcode 15 App —> Right click —> Show package contents —> Contents —> MacOS —> Xcode (Double click)
I don’t understand the downvote, in my case that was the error and the solution ‍♂️
